# How to check if a third party jar(JRecord) has any security issues

Tags: java, vulnerability, third-party

We are in the process of using a third party jar which is not available in Maven Repo. It needs to be manually downloaded for usage.

Is there any tool or way to find if the JAR has security issues?

http://jrecord.sourceforge.net/JRecord04.html is the website from which we downloaded the jars and sources codes also available as this is the open source project.

Please give some insights about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its open source you can download the source and review it yourselves. You should then use the self-built version to ensure the binary supplied online is not malicious.

Beyond that and googling for known issues with the package there isn't anything much you can do.

*What review process do you have to ensure libraries pulled via Maven are secure? And how does this differ?